# Как передать значение в следующий select после обработки ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Проблема, не понимаю, как заменить значения последнего `select` (в какой кабинет) в зависимости от предпоследнего. Подскажите куда копать, нет представления как ее доделать, уже много разных вариантов перебрал.

`Html` форма:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        
        <p>Откуда</p>
        <select name="building_from" id="building_id_from">
            <?php
            $buildings = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `buildings`" );
            $buildings = mysqli_fetch_all($buildings);
                foreach($buildings as $item) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $item[0]; ?>"><?php echo $item[1]; ?></option>
            <?php
                };
            ?>
        </select>

        <div id="result">
            <p>От какого кабинета</p>
            <select name="cabinet_from" id="cabinet_id_from">
                <?php 
                    $offices = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `building_offices` WHERE `building_ID` = 1" );
                    while($office_from = mysqli_fetch_assoc($offices)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $office_from['number']; ?>">к.<?php echo $office_from['number']; ?> | <?php echo $office_from['name']; ?> </option>
                <?php
                    };
                ?>
            </select>

            <p>Куда</p>
            <select name="building_to" id="building_id_to" disabled>
                <option value="">-- Выберите откуда --</option>
            </select>

            <div id="result1">
                
            </div>
<p>В какой кабинет</p>
<select name="cabinet_to" id="cabinet_id_to">
                <?php 
                    $offices = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `building_offices` WHERE `building_ID` = 1" );
                    while($office_from = mysqli_fetch_assoc($offices)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $office_from['number']; ?>">к.<?php echo $office_from['number']; ?> | <?php echo $office_from['name']; ?> </option>
                <?php
                    };
                ?>
        </select>

        </div>

    </form>
```

запрос `ajax`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#building_id_from").change(function(){
                var b_from = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./navigation/select.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {b_from: b_from},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    }
                })
            });

            $("#building_id_to").change(function(){
                var b_to = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./navigation/select.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {b_to: b_to},
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#result1").html(data);
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Обработчик `php`:

```
<?php
    require_once'../config/connect.php';
    $b_from = 0;
     if(isset($_POST['b_from'])) {
        $b_from = (int)$_POST['b_from'];
        ?>
    <p>От какого кабинета</p>
        <select name="cabinet_from" id="cabinet_id_from">
            <?php 
                $offices = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `building_offices` WHERE `building_ID` = $b_from" );
                while($office_from = mysqli_fetch_assoc($offices)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $office_from['number']; ?>">к.<?php echo $office_from['number']; ?> | <?php echo $office_from['name']; ?> </option>
            <?php
                };
            ?>
        </select>

        <p>Куда</p>
        <select name="building_to" id="building_id_to">
            <?php
            $buildings = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `buildings` WHERE `ID` != $b_from" );
            $buildings = mysqli_fetch_all($buildings);
                foreach($buildings as $item) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $item[0]; ?>"><?php echo $item[1]; ?></option>
            <?php
                };
            ?>
        </select>
        <?php print_r($_POST);
                echo $_POST; ?>
        <?php
 }

 if(isset($_POST['b_to'])) {
    $b_to = (int)$_POST['b_to'];

    echo $b_from;
    echo $b_to;
    print_r($_POST);
    echo $_POST;

 }
```

Comment: Заменить можете точно так же как Вы получаете другие селекты. Отслеживаете изменения нужного селекта, отправляете AJAX запрос на бекенд и можете просто в качестве ответа возвращать или массив, из которого потом сформируете `options` в `success` методе или возвращать сами же `options`, которые подставите в `select`. Можете для этого сделать отдельный AJAX action (грубо говоря какой-то флаг) по которому Вы бы различали, какое конкретно действие произошло и отталкиваясь от этого реализовываать разную логику и возвращать разный результат с backend.

Comment: Второй `ajax` как раз в моем понимании и должен отслеживать этот самый селект. Нужный мне селект для отслеживания - `id="building_id_to"`. В обработчике в самом низу я по условию пытался получить `$_POST` предпоследнего селекта, но не получаю ничего. И правильно ли я понимаю под "вернуть массив" - вернуть как json (еще не возвращал в таком формате и не работал)? И уже использовать его в качестве доделывания формы?

Comment: Да, как JSON. Вы ничего не получаете, потому что в селекте с ID `building_id_to`, в принципе ничего и нет, в форме он пустой и `disabled`. Если Вы рассчитывали отслеживать изменения в селектах который возвращаете с backend, убедитесь что они имеют уникальные идентификаторы + обработчик события нужно вешать когда элемент есть в DOM.

Comment: Ну то есть, когда Вы подставляете результат после его получения, у Вас дублируются элементы с одинаковым ID (а как мы знаем, ID должен быть уникальным + name Вы тоже дублируете) + Ваши ивент лиснеры ничего об этих элементах не знают, так как на момент инициализации лиснеров, этих элементов не существовало.